# Bokeh documentation integration with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, bokeh

A couple of python modules show the documentation on the right hand side in PyCharm (numpy, pandas etc.):

[image]

Bokeh does not and I wonder how can I point to a readable generated documentation for bokeh (pycharm guidelines are here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-external-documentation.html).

**Update**:

I've found that this one works for some methods:

```
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/{}generated/{module.name}.{element.name}.html
```

But it doesn't work for methods like `.line` where I get only meta information and the link returns a 404:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyph methods such as `line` are actually methods on the (capital F) `Figure` class. For historical reasons that are beyond changing at this point, the more more commonly used (lower case f) `figure` function just returns a `Figure` object. So the URL scheme you have above will not work in this instance.

As a concrete example, the location for the `line` method in the reference docs that you can presumably configure for PyCharm, is here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.line

Comment: Putting all of this togther, that means you have to add an entry for `bokeh.plotting` for example that looks like this `https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#{module.name}.{class.name}.{element.name}` (just tested, this seems to work for `p.line(...)` e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to run "Hello Bokeh" in Pycharm CE:

*(Menu)* Run > Edit Configuration

Name **hello_bokeh**

Script path **G:\Users\frederic\Anaconda3\Scripts\bokeh-script.py**

Parameters **serve --show C:\data\design\machine_learning\first_project\vae_july_2018\bokeh\hello_bokeh.py**

Then validate by **Ok**

*(Menu)* Run > Run 'hello_bokeh'